# Moving tempfile to other folder makes it unaccessible

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows

In my asp.net application on Windows Server 2008, I have code like this

```
tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName()
... Write data to tempfile ...
File.Move(tempfile, storageDir + fileName)
```

This works just fine. The problem is afterwards when I am trying to access the file from outside of ASP.NET. I get access denied, even though the user I am accessing from have (recursive) read rights to the *storageDir* folder.

It seems that the moved file doesn't inherit rights from the folder it is moved into. Is this correct, and if so, is there an easy way to fix that?

Right now as a direct fix I have changed every instance of File.Move() in my ASP.NET application to File.Copy() + File.Delete(), which seems to fix the problem. But it feels like a very dirty way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is by design:

[Moving a file does not recalculate inherited permissions.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/24/717181.aspx)

I think you already described the easiest way to fix this: "copy and delete" instead of "move".

Answer (score 0):

The application is probably hogging the file.

You might need to release the resource. It's hard to tell from your code snippet exactly how you're treating the file, but try something like `tempfile.Dispose()`.